# DropDownList doesn't work with the codebehind C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I tried to make a DropDownList. It is working when i do it inside the aspx file, but it doesn't work inside the codebehind.

```
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlChannel" runat="server">
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsChannel" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Monitor_SQL %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM TABLE"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlChannel" runat="server"  DataSourceID="sdsChannel"  AutoPostBack="True" DataTextField="Kanal"> 
</asp:DropDownList>
</asp:Panel>
```

Then I tried it with the codebehind in C#:

```
   public Panel GetDropDownList()
{
    // Create drop down list and data source
    Panel pnlChannel = new Panel();
    pnlChannel.ID = "pnlChannel";
    DropDownList ddlChannel = new DropDownList();
    ddlChannel.ID = "ddlChannel";
    ListItem limDefault = new ListItem();
    SqlDataSource sdsChannel = new SqlDataSource();
    sdsChannel.ID = "sdsChannel";

    // Configure data source
    sdsChannel.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Monitor_SQL"].ConnectionString;
    sdsChannel.SelectCommand = "SELECT * From TABlE";


    // Configure drop down list
    ddlChannel.DataTextField = "Kanal";
    ddlChannel.DataValueField = "Kanal";
    ddlChannel.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
    ddlChannel.DataSourceID = "sdsChannel";
    ddlChannel.AutoPostBack = true;



    // Configure default list item
    limDefault.Selected = true;
    limDefault.Text = "Alle";
    limDefault.Value = "-1";

    //Add controls to static panel in footer
    ddlChannel.Items.Add(limDefault);
    pnlChannel.Controls.Add(ddlChannel);
    pnlChannel.Controls.Add(sdsChannel);
    return pnlChannel;
}
```

Why isn't it working? + I will not use both, i want to use one of these opinions

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  What is it doing?  What do you expect it to do?  When you step through in a debugger, where does it go wrong?

Comment: Why are you creating a new dropdownlist in your code behind? You can just use the existing one by using ddlChannel, instead of setting this to a new DropdownList ...

Comment: @David If if do it in the codebehind there is a DropDownList but there is nothing inside the list. So I think the itemlist is wrong but I can't find a fault.

Comment: @StevenLemmens I could, but I don't want to use both options, I want to use only one.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment:

> If if do it in the codebehind there is a DropDownList but there is nothing inside the list

You never bound the control to the data:

```
ddlChannel.DataBind();
```

Comment: So if I do it like this, there is it is still not working. Do I have to write for ex. the asp:panel inside the aspx file or should it work if I only write the code in the codebehind file?

Comment: @fusionchart_help: Do you ever add the `Panel` to the page?  The posted code doesn't cover that.  You may also need to "bind" in some way the `SqlDataSource`, I haven't really used declarative data sources so I'm not sure.

Comment: I tried to bind it but it is still not working, the error says that it isn't connected to the site. Is the .Controls not working?